# How to add a Dynamic Attribute on Variable with Twig?

Tags: symfony, variables, dynamic, attributes, twig

In my project (symfony/flex 1.1) i had a method "displayMenuAndSubMenu([...])" (as a service) to build menu and submenus on a multidimensionnal array.

*NB: Some menus may not have submenus*

My problem is that when I want to render my menu board in a html.twig template,I can not reproduce the incremental variables $i and $a. Indeed, with my actually twig code I get a simple string output :-(

I have read somewhere that a custom twig extension will allow me to work around this difficulty.

But I find it very complicated to implement a simple counter.

So my questions are:

- Is there a simpler way to do this in a html.twig template ?
- Do I have to go through in a php.twig template (so disgustin in my sense) ?
- Am I doomed to define a twig extension ? (And if so, do you have an example ?)

Thanks

#### ContentService::displayMenuAndSubmenu

```
    public function displayMenuAndSubMenu(CategoryService $categoryService, CategoryTypeService $categoryTypeService)
        {
            $categoryId = $categoryService->getCategoryId('Primary');
            $categoryTypeId = $categoryTypeService->getCategoryTypeId('Menu');
    
            // Getting primary menus
            $primaryMenu = $this->em->getRepository('App\Entity\Content')->findByCategoryTypeAndCategory($categoryTypeId, $categoryId);

            // Constructing MainMenu with menus and submenus
            $i = 0;
            $menu = [];
            $submenu = [];
            $mainMenu = [];
            foreach ($primaryMenu as $keyMenu => $menuItem) {
                $menu[$i] = [ 'menu_' . $i => [
                    'id' => $menuItem->getId(),
                    'name' => $menuItem->getName(),
                    'body' => $menuItem->getBody(),
                    'slug' => $menuItem->getSlug(),
                    ] 
                ];

                // Getting secondary menu
                $secondaryMenu = $this->em->getRepository('App\Entity\Content')->findByParent($menuItem->getId());
                $a = 0;
                foreach ($secondaryMenu as $keySubmenu => $subMenuItem) {
                    $submenu[$i][$a] = [ 'submenu_' . $i . '_' . $a => [ 
                                                    'id' => $subMenuItem->getId(),
                                                    'name' => $subMenuItem->getName(),
                                                    'body' => $subMenuItem->getBody(),
                                                    'slug' => $subMenuItem->getSlug(),
                                                 ]
                                             ];
                
                    $menu[$i] += $submenu[$i][$a];
                    $a++;
                }

                $mainMenu += $menu; 
                $i++;

            }

            return $mainMenu;
        }
```

#### _menu.html.twig

```
    {% set i = 0 %}
    {% for menu in menu_items %}

    {% set a = 0 %}

        <div class="center">
        <section class="primary-menu">

             {% if 'menu_'~i~'.slug' is not empty %}
             <header class="enter">{{ 'menu_'~i~'.name' }}</header>
    
                {% for submenu in 'menu_'~i~'.submenu' %} 
                <article>
                 <a href= {{ 'submenu_'~i~'_'~a~'.slug' }}" alt="{{ 'submenu_'~i~'_'~a~'.body' }}"class="para1">{{ 'submenu_'~i~'_'~a~'.name' }}</a>
                </article>
                {% endfor %}

            {% else %}
             <header class="enter"><a href="{{ 'menu_'~i~'.slug' }}" alt="{{ 'menu_'~i~'.body' }}">{{ 'menu_'~i~'.name' }}</a></header>
            {% endif %} 
        </section>
        {% set i = i + 1 %}
        {% endfor %}
```

### dump($mainMenu) on ContentService class output

```
    array:5 [▼
      0 => array:4 [▼
        "menu_0" => array:4 [▼
          "id" => "a420742f-124a-11e9-a1fd-805e4fe8b43b"
          "name" => "Menu 0"
          "body" => "Primary menu0"
          "slug" => null
        ]
        "submenu_0_0" => array:4 [▼
          "id" => "a4208ec3-124a-11e9-a1fd-805e4fe8b43b"
          "name" => "Submenu 0"
          "body" => "Secondary menu0"
          "slug" => "menu-0-submenu-0"
        ]
        "submenu_0_1" => array:4 [▼
          "id" => "a420a70d-124a-11e9-a1fd-805e4fe8b43b"
          "name" => "Submenu 1"
          "body" => "Secondary menu1"
          "slug" => "menu-0-submenu-1"
        ]
        "submenu_0_2" => array:4 [▼
          "id" => "a420ba8f-124a-11e9-a1fd-805e4fe8b43b"
          "name" => "Submenu 2"
          "body" => "Secondary menu2"
          "slug" => "menu-0-submenu-2"
        ]
      ]
      1 => array:1 [▼
        "menu_1" => array:4 [▼
          "id" => "a4205c9f-124a-11e9-a1fd-805e4fe8b43b"
          "name" => "Home"
          "body" => "Home menu"
          "slug" => "home"
        ]
      ]
      2 => array:4 [▶]
      3 => array:4 [▶]
      4 => array:4 [▶]
    ]
```